# Override App API of IONIC (to change the behavior of hardware back button)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to remove the code line that exists the app when the hardware back button is pressed in the code source of App API.
Here is the code inside app.js that I want to change:

```
App.prototype.goBack = function() {
    if (this._menuCtrl && this._menuCtrl.isOpen()) {
        return this._menuCtrl.close();
    }
    var navPromise = this.navPop();
    if (navPromise === null) {
        // no views to go back to
        // let's exit the app
        if (this._config.getBoolean('navExitApp', true)) {
            (void 0) /* console.debug */ ;
             this._plt.exitApp();
        }
    }
    return navPromise;
};
```

What I want to do is simply delete the line  this._plt.exitApp();
Is there any clean way to do so beside changing the code source directly.
I tried the method  [registerBackButtonAction(fn, priority)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction) it worked, But it's really too slow (650 ms) on a samsung A3 2014. 
When I changed the code source directly the performance was really good.
Is there any way to this cleanly?

Comment: I'm afraid the only way is to override the `registerBackButtonAction(fn, priority) ` method :(

Comment: I'll try that though I m afraid the performance will be the same.

Comment: The performance is the same :(